# Background of the Image created from Bitmap

Tags: android

I am trying to create a signature component where the user can write his signature on the view and the resulting bitmap being saved as an image. I am able to achieve this successfully.
But my issue is that the background color is of the image being saved is always transparent. In my onDraw method i do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

and while writing to the file system i do the following:

```
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

The view on the device while capturing the signature is as shown in the image below:
[image]

After the bitmap is written to the file system the image is as below:

[image]

Could some one kindly help me with this. I would like me image to have the same background as the canvas.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it seems like you want to save the entire view as a bitmap instead of the path object. To do this you can simply save the `DrawingCache` of the view as a `Bitmap`.

```
myView.buildDrawingCache()
Bitmapt b = myView.getDrawingCache()
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

Comment: Hello Slayton.
Thanks a ton. Exactly what i wanted. :-)